# Getting a queryset using a foreign key field in the "other side" of a foreign key relation

Tags: django, django-models

Forgive me if the question does not make sense, trying to teach myself django. I've been trying to search how to do this but i'm not sure if i'm using the right words in my search.

I have the following models.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserGroupHeader(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserGroupDetail(models.Model):
    usergroupheader = models.ForeignKey(UserGroupHeader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

How do i get a query set from the Category model using the UserGroupHeader? so far what i've got is something like this `UserGroupHeader.objects.get(pk=9).usergroupdetail_set.all()`, now from the result of this how do i get the Category model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you are trying to do, but in general, while querying, you can follow relations using double underscores. Below are a couple of possible queries:

```
my_group_header = UserGroupHeader.objects.get(...)
Category.objects.filter(usergroupdetail__usergroupheader=my_group_header) # Gets Category objects related to my_group_header through UserGroupDetail model

Category.objects.filter(usergroupdetail__usergroupheader__code='abc') # Gets Category objects related to UserGroupHeader object with code 'abc' through UserGroupDetail model

UserGroupHeader.objects.filter(usergroupdetail__category__code='abc') # Gets UserGroupHeader objects related to Category object with code 'abc' through UserGroupDetail model
```

Comment: Thank you, the second one is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your query `UserGroupHeader.objects.get(pk=9).usergroupdetail_set.all()` would return a `QuerySet` of `UserGroupDetail` objects. In order to get the `category` of each `UserGroupDetail`, you can:

```
for user_group_detail in UserGroupHeader.objects.get(pk=9).usergroupdetail_set.all():
    category = user_group_detail.category
    print(category. description)
```

Or something similar according to your needs